# (Swift)How to dectect a "fieldEditor" resignFirstResponder() (Mac/Cocoa)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

What I intend to do is validate four NSTextFields, I will try to make sure that all of them are filled correctly, and completely.

[textField and alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxDRk.gif)

As the picture shows: if a user types anything in the 1st NSTextField, types **something wrong or leaves it blank** in the 2nd NSTextField, press Enter or click outside the boundary, it should show an alert, and try to **stop the user from resigning from the 2nd NSTextField**, and he should confirm his input in 2nd NSTextField.

What I have tried and the problems I faced:

1. Use textFieldShouldEndEditing(_:)

When I type something. Wrong, show an alert and return false. It runs well.

But if I type nothing, textFieldShouldEndEditing(_:) will not invoke. (Because it won't be triggered without typing)

```
 func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {
    if control.stringValue != validInput{
       showAlert()
       return false
    }else{
       return true
    }        
}// plz ignore the delegation
```

2. CustomNSTextField & resignFirstResponder()

When the user clicked NSTextField, NSTextField would becomeFirstResponder(), followed by ResignFirstResponder() because the FieldEditor would enter. So it is invalid to monitor resignFirstResponder().

3. Use textFieldShouldEndEditing(_:)

When I type something wrong or type nothing, press Enter or click outside the boundary, show an alert, but it is difficult to stop the following functions: for example, if I click the button "open", it may show an alert and an openFile dialog in the meantime.

What may solve my problems：

1. Whether there is a trick that invokes textFieldDidBeginEditing (_:) when NSTextField resignFirstResponder() ?
2. Whether there is a function that monitors the window's current fieldEditor resignFirstResponder(), and it can return false while I want the user to confirm his input.

Comment: How do you validate a text field if the user didn't visit it? Do you check if the start time is before the end time?

Comment: @Willeke I just simplified my code for reading, I created 4 variables for the 4 NSTextField(e.g. tempText1, tempText2... tempText4 ), everytime a user types in the 1st NSTextField, I'll change a tempText1 via controlTextDidChange: method. I'll check whether tempText1..4 are not nil at the end.

Comment: Do you want to know when a different row is selected?

Comment: @Willke I want to know when the fieldEditor for the NSTextfield resigns the first responder, that means the NSTextfield has been clicked, and no matter whether it has been inputted or not, I can get notified when the user ends editing, validate and determine whether editing should be finished.

Comment: Tip: don't validate all fields in `textShouldEndEditing`. It's very annoying if a field can't be validated because another field has a typo.

Comment: Storyboard/NSViewController or XIB/NSWindow?

Comment: Thx for ur advise, @Willeke.Now I'm trying to write a custom FieldEditor for NSTextFieldCell to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

I found it NOT as difficult as I thought to write a custom fieldEditor. Follow the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LL3fgXTrMQA&list=PLE83F832121568D36&index=80&t=487s). I post the essential part of my code here for anyone who is facing similar problems.

```
class CustomFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {
    static var durationFieldEditor: CustomFieldEditor = {
        let customFieldEditor = CustomFieldEditor()
        return fieldEditor
    }()

    override func fieldEditor(for controlView: NSView) -> NSTextView? {
        return Self.customFieldEditor
    }
}

class CustomFieldEditor: NSTextView {

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect, textContainer container: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect, textContainer: container)
        commonInit()
    }

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        // condition
        return super.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        // condition
        return super.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        isFieldEditor = true
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```